# How to paste original values in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

While I paste some text in a cell in excel, it changes it into some other value. For example, if I paste "5SEPT" it gets changed into 5-Sep. If I paste 369E8, it gets changed into 3.69E+10

This is very annoying. How can I paste the original value in excel?

Comment: Looks like the orignal cell and the destination cell have different formats. Does ist also happen when jou set the same format for both?

Comment: Isn't there a paste-special with suitable options.

Comment: I am pasting it from an external text file. If I simply type in excel, then also the value gets changed.

Comment: @Niks set the format of the cell to `Text`

Comment: "5SEPT" is being assumed to be a date and is then displayed with the closest "correct" standard date format for your convenience.  "369E8" could be just text but Excel is interpreting it as scientific notation and formatting it "correctly" for your convenience.  If you plan to use these in Excel as a date and number, respectively, accept what Excel does and then change the format to what you want.  If you just want identical text strings, format the cells to text before you paste as boboes suggests or use paste special as wendy krieger suggests.